# Reactive dataframe in rCharts

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I would make my rChart functions consider a reactive dataframe subsetted according to the parameters selected in the UI. Unfortunately, the output returns always the very same plot, ignoring the reactive dataframe `dt3`. 
Here a screen representing the usual input and an example of the subsetted dataframe it should consider. The complete dataset is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Maurizio-Mario/app_rChart_rain/blob/master/precipitation_temperature_data.txt).

[image]

As you can see, the dataframe `dt3` is correctly subsetted, but rCharts ignores it, returning always that very same plot.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts) # rCharts_0.4.2
options(RCHART_LIB = 'nvd3')

shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Alpine weather stations"),
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = 'station', lab = "Station",
                    choices = sort(as.character(dt$Weather_station)), 
                    selected = NULL),
        sliderInput(inputId = "year", lab = "Years:",
                    min = 1980,
                    max = 2011,
                    value = c(1980, 1985)),
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "data", lab = "Select",
                           choices = c("Mean temperature" = "meanTemp",
                                       "Precipitation" = "precipitation"))

    ),
    mainPanel(
        showOutput("chart1", "nvd3")
        #dataTableOutput("dt3")        #Used for the example screenshot
    )
)
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts) # rCharts_0.4.2
options(RCHART_LIB = 'nvd3')

dt <- read.table("precipitation_temperature_data.txt", header = TRUE, dec = ".", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
#output$dt3 <- renderDataTable({        # Used to create the screenshot subset
dt3 <- reactive({                       # Used to create reactive dataframe  
    range <- input$year[1] : input$year[2]
    station2 <- input$station
    dt2 <- dt[dt$Weather_station == unlist(station2) & dt$Year %in% range, ]
    dt2 <- as.data.frame(dt2)
    dt2
})

output$chart1 <- renderChart({
    validate(
        need(input$data != "", "Please select your data.")
    )

    if(input$data == "Precipitation"){
    n2 <- nPlot(Precipitation ~ Year, data = dt3(), group = "Weather_station", type = 'multiBarChart')
    }else if(input$data == "Mean_temperature"){
        n2 <- nPlot(Mean_temperature ~ Year, data = dt3(), group = "Weather_station", type = 'multiBarChart')
    }
    n2$set(dom = 'chart1')
    n2


})
})
```

I am aware of the usual problems with this kind of chart (such the use of `renderChart2`) but since it never changes, I do not know how to act, even with the help and question from the [rCharts page](http://ramnathv.github.io/rNVD3/).

Here is the session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.3      tools_3.2.4     whisker_0.3-2   yaml_2.1.13     Rcpp_0.12.4     rCharts_0.4.2   RJSONIO_1.3-0  
[8] grid_3.2.4      lattice_0.20-33
```

Comment: Version `rCharts_0.4.2`.

Comment: Please make it reproducible, I am getting error: `Error in dt$Weather_station : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. Also, add `sessionInfo()` to your post, do we need to install rHighcharts library as well?

Comment: Here is the session info. I am sorry, but the code I posted does not throw any kind of error, checked again to be sure. Be aware, there are a couple of comments in the code, even if they do not interfere. I did not install `rHighcharts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If statement doesn't match input from ui, change `if() else if()` to below:

```
 if(input$data == "precipitation"){
    n2 <- nPlot(Precipitation ~ Year, data = dt3(), group = "Weather_station", type = 'multiBarChart')
    } else if(input$data == "meanTemp"){
        n2 <- nPlot(Mean_temperature ~ Year, data = dt3(), group = "Weather_station", type = 'multiBarChart')
    }
```

Comment: It happens, glad it worked, you might also want to change checkboxGroupInput to radioButtons.

Comment: I would prefer it, but I am afraid the choices are too much (33), thus creating an heavy UI.

Comment: @Worice if the choice is A or B, then radio makes more sense, no? i.e.: precipitation or meanTemp.

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking about the selectInput.